# If number A is higher than number B, keep asking for lower user Input on number A

Tags: java, swing

NB: Java beginner!
I am trying to make a program that asks the user to input two integers (Using JOption Pane dialog boxes). The program should then find the sum of all the numbers between the two input integers. For example if the user inputs 1 and 8, the program would show in System.out: 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36. The first input dialog asks the user to enter a number, and the second to enter a higher number than the first. I want the program to check if number 2 actually is higher than number 1, and if not, tell the user that number 2 should be higher and prompt for a new entry.

I am currently unable to check if number 2 is higher than number 1

I have tried using different if statement and a while loop. I manage to get the program to show a message dialog if the second number is higher than the first, and ask the user for a new input. However I am unable to get the new input from the user, check if it is correct, and if it is continue with the calculations.

```java
    package numbersum;

    public class NumberSum {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Write a number :" );
      String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Write a larger number :" );
      int number1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);
      int number2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);

      if ( number2 <= number1 ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The second number must be higher 
        than the first");
      }
      int sum=0;
      for ( int i = number1; i <= number2; i++ ) {
        sum = sum + i;
        System.out.print( i + "+" );
      }
      System.out.print( "=" + sum );
    }
```

Comment: make sure you format your code properly befor submitting your question, so it's easily readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a while loop and provide the JOptionPane untill the user enters valid numbers. Also be sure to test what happens with your application if the user inserts a non numeric value, it probably will crash at the moment :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initially set the number 2 smaller than number 1
    int number2 = 0;
    int number1 = 1;
    while (number2 < number1) {
        String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number :");
        String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a larger number :");
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
        if (number2 < number1)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The second number must be higher!");
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
        System.out.print(i + "+");
    }
    System.out.print("=" + sum);
}
```